# How to start this GMaps demo with keyboard focus on it?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, keyboard, focus

I'm looking at this GMaps example, and I would like it to start with focus of keyboard (so I can navigate using diretional keys and '+' and '-' for zoom), is there a way?

The example code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<style type="text/css"> 
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style> 
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 
  <div id="map_canvas"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you found the answer already, but leaving my solution here for reference anyway. I had the same issue and fixed it with some jQuery help:

```
  $(document).keyup(function(event) {
    var offset = 128;
    switch(event.keyCode) {
      case 37: //leftArrow
        map.panBy(-offset,0);
        break;
      case 38: //upArrow
        map.panBy(0,-offset);
        break;
      case 39: //rightArrow
        map.panBy(offset,0);
        break;
      case 40: //downArrow
        map.panBy(0,offset);
        break;
      case 189: //-
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1);
        break;
      case 187: //+
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
        break;
    }
  });
```

And I have `keyboardShortcuts: false` on the map's [MapOptions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapOptions).

Comment: Actually, I never found an answer for this. You re-implemented the commands? It's a workaround.. but what about if the commands change in the future? ;)

Comment: Sure, it's a hack, but it has the advantage of allowing me to change the panning and zooming offset, which are additional features I needed. [panBy() and setZoom()](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) are standard API methods, so what I've re-implemented isn't much.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the answer is: it's not possible using just javascript.